# Badge in Careers profile

Tags: feature-request, badges, jobs, information-display

Badges are like award awarded by Stack Overflow  .. and it's quite good to show  badges in our Careers 2.0 profile as per the image below, but only add tag badges (like php ,xml, etc.) not like marshal or copy-editor.  There should be option to add any allowed 5 badges that we'd like to show off.

> [image]

Comment: Non tag badges (like Copy Editor) don't really have any meaning towards your skill level and not really relevant to careers. I don't totally disagree, but don't think it's really right. Just link to your profile where the badges are all shiny and in place. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ya agreed and also telling(only tag badge) in request

Comment: Some of the really hard to get badges are definitely representative of your dedication of the site. Willingness to help others and support the community seems like a good trait to show off.

Comment: Make it possible to choose badges yourself. There is no need to restrict it to tag-only badges then, since the user may choose for herself what looks most promising to an employer. Nobody will pick the (awesome) `copy-editor` badge if they don't think it will help them land a job.