# Expose badges in the Careers 2.0 profile

Tags: feature-request, badges, jobs

It would be nice if my Stack Overflow badges were shown next to my reputation in my Careers 2.0 profile page.

It will help keep Careers consistent with the rest of Stack Exchange as reputation and badges always appear together. Secondly, I think it just looks more professional when employers can see my gold, silver medals.

I'm not suggesting exposing the badge names and information; only the count of them next to the reputation.

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail.  Like why you think it would be nice?

Comment: First, the reputation and badges always appear together anywhere. Second, I think it just looks more professional when employers can see my gold, silver medals. I didn't mean to expose there the badges names and info, only count them next to my rep.

Comment: Then edit that into your post.  A feature request should explain why in more detail than "it would be nice".  Otherwise, how will a dev know what you want, or if it is worth the time/effort to implement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Badge in Careers profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161791/badge-in-careers-profile)

Comment: @NullPoiиteя: Your feature request asks for certain badges (like 'top 10%', etc for tags) to be displayed. This one asks for the badge **counts** to be displayed. The two concepts are different.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The top X% is only about reputation and is already shown there. You can be in top 10% for a tag without having any badges. He's asking for bronze/silver/gold tag badges. I agree it is certainly not a duplicate.

Comment: @kapep: I know how the top X% works. The point is that it shows certain tags, and you can actually choose to alter that list. NullPoiиteя's request is similar, in that it asks to show individual (top) badges, **not** your total badge count.

Comment: No thanks, I'd rather not have badges (which I find largely meaningless) show up (and I certainly don't want them to have a significant impact on any decisions made regarding me, which they may if they show up).